# Showing list of lync windows on click of a button

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, winapi, lync-client-sdk

I am trying to develop a winform app where there is a button. On button click, list of lync windows should appear as they appear when we hover over the lync icon in system taskbar as below.

[image: The blacked out portion contains the names of the chat participants]

How can i get the same functionality on button click on my winform.

I am using Lync SDK 2013 but am fine with 2010 also.

So in summary, **i want to simulate the function when we hover over the lync icon in taskbar in a button on my form. On click of the button, the list of the conversations would be displayed with the active/most recent one highlighted and clicking on that would take to that particular conversation window.** 
Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for all Lync conversations, use the [ConversationManager.Conversations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.conversationmanager.conversations_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncctrsl%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property in the SDK. There are also ConversationAdded and ConversationRemoved events on the ConversationManger, so you can keep your list updated in real-time.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit ugly, but when I tried to detect conversation windows, I had no other choice than enumerating all windows using the Windows API function [`EnumWindows`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/EnumWindows.html) and then check for the window class `"LyncConversationWindowClass"`. But this was more than a year ago using Lync 2010 - don't know if it works with Lync 2013 or if there is a better solution yet.

At least, this code doesn't require the Lync SDK. ;-)

Here is my code snippet, I hope it helps:

```
void Test()
{
    int conversationWindowCount = WindowDetector.Count("LyncConversationWindowClass");
}

static class WindowDetector
{
    private delegate bool CallBackPtr(int hwnd, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int EnumWindows(CallBackPtr callPtr, int lPar);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

    private static readonly object Lock = new object();

    private static int _count;
    private static string _className;

    private static bool EnumWindowsCallback(int hwnd, int lparam)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(255);
        GetClassName(new IntPtr(hwnd), sb, sb.Capacity);
        string className = sb.ToString();

        if (className == _className)
        {
            _count++;
        }

        // return true to continue enumerating or false to stop
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns the count of windows which have the specified class name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="className">The window class name to look for (case-sensitive).</param>
    public static int Count(string className)
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            _count = 0;
            _className = className;

            EnumWindows(EnumWindowsCallback, 0);

            return _count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...even i was worried that we will have to use Win Apis.